# How do you say “you first” in Latin with all the options for saying you

Tags: english-to-latin-translation

I would like to say “you first” in Latin. 
With all the different ways to say you (tu/vos....I can’t remember it that well from school)....with the correct corresponding first....
Thanks so much!!!!

Answer (score 2):

In the comments on the other answer, I think we've concluded that you could use "tu primum", "tibi primum", or "te primum" depending on whether "you" is the subject, beneficiary, or object of the implied action, or you could say "sis primus" (to a man) or "sis prima" (to a woman).

In the plural, these would be "vos primum", "vobis primum", "vos primum", "sitis primi", and "sitis primae", respectively.

There is no *tu* or *vos* with the adjective since in that case the subjunctive mood must be made explicit by including the verb, and once the verb is explicit, nominative case pronouns are redundant and omitted.

Answer (score 1):

I would paraphrase "You first" as "You are the first" or "You must go first".
In the first case, "the first" is a predicate. A nominative case could be used.
In the second case, "first" is an adverb.

Primus means "first" and is a first declension adjective.
Primum is the adverb form.

If singular, the possibilities are: tu primus, tu prima.

If plural: vos primi, vos primae.

Comment: You forgot to mention that the adverb is *primum*; it will often be an adverb that is needed.  Also, the case of the pronoun may not be nominative, though it usually would be.  If we are waiting in line at the bread dole, "tibi primum" might be more appropriate.

Comment: I was in doubt about *primum* also. I didn't consider the dative case, thanks.

Comment: I would actually use the adjective instead of the adverb for this, even if English thinks otherwise. With plural the adjective should be plural (*primi*) and one has to switch to feminine when appropriate (*prima, primae*).

Comment: @JoonasIlmavirta To me, *tu primum* sounds as natural as *tu quoque*.  On the other hand, modifying a personal pronoun with an ordinal number sounds...special.  Can you cite examples?

Comment: @CMonsour Unfortunately I can't. To me *tu quoque* sounds much more natural than *tu primum*, but I fully acknowledge that this is based on nothing rigorous. Can you write an answer focusing on the adverbial side of things and maybe comparing the two? It's always best to have different views and many answers.

Comment: @CMonsour When I was looking for *primus* in my Latin dictionary (Latin-Dutch), I remember finding *primum* as an adverb with the translation *also*.

Comment: @JoonasIlmavirta OK, so I'll settle for an example of a personal pronoun being modified by any adjective other than a predicate adjective.

Comment: And I think "tu primus" means "you are first" ("es" implied)--a mere recognition of fact or state, whereas "tu primum" means "you first" in that both resolve to "you go first" or "please, you eat first" or the like, depending on the situation, and can express a wish as well as a fact.

Comment: Whereas to express a wish with an adjective would require an explicit subjunctive: "sis primus", not "tu primus".